# React: Mui 5: Failed to minify the code from this file: ./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/styled

Tags: reactjs, build, material-ui

After update to MUI 5 I am trying to build the project but get error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBLHe.png)
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

```
    ./node_modules/@mui/material/styles/styled.js:6:7
```

tried:

- updated react-scripts to the latest version,
- rm -rf node_modules rm
- rf package-lock.json
- Run npm cache clean --force
- npm install

----all above not helped

Comment: I guess there might be some version issue. I recommend you to remove node modules and install again using "npm install" command,Which might be resolve your issue.